# How to know how many users downloaded App from App store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I recently added a new App to app store. Now I would like to know how many users have downloaded it. Its a free App.

Answer (score 6):

Go To **itunesconnect.com** log in with the same credentials you used for getting into the Developer Program, go to **Sales and Trends** module. There also is a mobile version of this app.

Answer (score 4):

The most convenient way is to use [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa) and check the Sales & Trends Tab, but it gives the broad idea of number of downloads, where as you can use [Flurry Analytics](https://dev.flurry.com/createProjectSelectPlatform.do) to know how many users are using your app.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/). The tool Apple gives you to do exactly what you want right now.

Answer (score 2):

## 2023

In App Store Connect:

1. Select the Analytics activity
2. Select the Metrics tab
3. From the dropdown on the left, select installations
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Apple just updated https://itunesconnect.apple.com site you can adjust the date range in the middle of screen (using the slider) or by adjusting the dates on top left corner after navigating to sale and trends screen to see how many downloads you have had.
 [image]